# How to handle Run 1 ESS job 5 times with multiple parameters .Means every time parameters should be change. ON OIC Integration

Tags: oracle, integration, oracle-integration-cloud

I want to run 1 ESS job 5 times with multiple parameters . Means every time parameter should be change.
How to handle this through OIC Integration.

In 1 ESS Job will run 5 times with different parameter in OIC .
have to run  ESS jobs each ess jobs having multiple and different parameters on each run how to handle this on OIC.